# piece of html+javascript that finds if number from an input is prime then displays the result

Tags: javascript, html

School project. I must design a page that contains an input box, a button that sends the entered number to the function, and a paragraph that displays the result. Here's my progress as of now, problem is it just says "false" everytime. Sorry for the triviality of the question, i'm a total newb with web coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function isPrime($n)
{
    $i=2;
if ($n==2){
return true;
}

$sqrtN = sqrt($n);
while ($i<= $sqrtN){
if ($n % $i ==0){
return false;
}
$i++;
}
return true;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
Value: <input type="number" id="n"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="isPrime(n)">
</form>

<p id="derp">sdvfsdg</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("derp").innerHTML = isPrime(n);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first of all remove these lines from the code as they seem irrelevant to the question

$sqrtN = sqrt($n);
while ($i<= $sqrtN){
if ($n % $i ==0){
return false;
}
$i++;
}
return true;

. . writing answer. wait

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are setting the content of the derp once and for all before pressing the button

```
function isPrime($n)
{
    $i=2;
    if ($n==2){
      document.getElementById("derp").innerHTML = "True";
    }

    $sqrtN = sqrt($n);
    while ($i<= $sqrtN){
      if ($n % $i ==0){
        document.getElementById("derp").innerHTML = "False";
      }
      $i++;
    }
  document.getElementById("derp").innerHTML = "True";
}
```

And not sure you really need the $ everywhere - that's a PHP thing

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that'll work for your case... You should execute the code on click AFTER entering the value

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

</script>

</head>
<body>
Value: <input type="number" id="n"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="checkPrime()">  <!--use function on click-->
</form>

<p id="derp">sdvfsdg</p>

<script>
function isPrime(num)
{
    var isPrime = true; //initially set to true
   for(var i=2; i<num; i++){      
        if(num%i == 0){  //if the num gets divide by any other number except itself
            isPrime = false;
        }
   }
   return isPrime;
}
function checkPrime(){   //function that gets called on send button click
    var number = document.getElementById("n").value;   //get the value of input
    number = parseInt(number);    //since it's a string,convert it into number
    document.getElementById("derp").innerHTML = isPrime(number);    //check if prime and display result
}

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but not only for numbers under 100. Tested it with 11 digit numbers and the result was correct. Thanks alot

Comment: @Kinook yeah sorry I edited the code for all numbers :) forgot to remove the comment 
Kindly accept the answer by marking as accepted and up vote if you want
I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You had not used input field value at all, that was your mistake

```html
Value:
<input type="number" id="n">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Sebd" onclick="x()">
</form>
<p id="derp">sdvfsdg</p>
<div id="try">jdfs</div>
<script>
  function x() {
    document.getElementById('derp').innerHTML = isPrime(Number(document.getElementById('n').value));
  }

  function isPrime(n) {
    i = 2;
    if (n == 2) {
      return true;
    }

    sqrtN = Math.sqrt(n);
    document.getElementById('try').innerHTML = n;
    while (i <= sqrtN) {
      document.getElementById('try').innerHTML = 'try';
      if (n % i == 0) {

        return false;
      }
      i++;
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```